# Proof that a number and its multiplicative inverse have the same sign

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am trying to prove that if a number $a > 0$, then its multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$ is also $>0$.

What I have done thus far is this:

Using the trichotomy property for the real numbers, I consider the following cases, where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all positive real numbers:

1. $a^{-1} = \frac{1}{a} = 0$.  I'm trying to show this for ALL a, but when $a=1$, this possibility violates the Nontriviality Property, so $a^{-1} \neq 0$.
2. $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{P}$. In this case, there is nothing to show.
3. $-a^{-1} \in \mathbb{P}$. Or, in other words, $a^{-1}$ is negative. In this case, I assume that I would need to show that this implies that $a < 0$ (or, equivalently, $-a \in \mathbb{P}$, but I am not sure how to prove this part. I want to use the Positivity Axiom of $\mathbb{R}$ that states that "if $a$, $b > 0$, then both $ab>0$ and $a+b>0$". I was thinking of perhaps using the contrapositive, that "if $ab<0$, then either $a<0$ or $b<0$", but I am not sure how to express it in a mathematically rigourous manner.

If anyone could please assist me on this, I would be eternally grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Hint. Can you see how to apply the rules you know (i.e. have proved) that tell you the sign of a product when you know the signs of the numbers being multiplied?

Comment: I'm not sure I have proved them. But even so, how to mathematically rigourously express working backwards with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a>0$ and $-a^{-1}>0$, what about $(-a^{-1})a$?

Comment: Yes, but does that rigourously prove that if $a>0$ and $(-a^{1})a >0$ that it must be the case that $-a^{-1} > 0$? Perhaps I'm overthinking this, but what I've learned since starting to study this stuff is to never assume anything.

Comment: Well, in this case you need to prove first that $1>0.$

Comment: Did that already. Question still stands.

Comment: @JessyCat You're mixing up the logic. You have that $a>0$ and you are stuck on the possibility that $-a^{-1}>0$ right? Well, assume for the moment that it's so. Then we must have $-1=a(-a^{-1})>0$ by the "Positivity Axiom".

Comment: And that's a contradiction.

Comment: With the Trichotemy, yep! Can't have both $-1<0$ and $-1>0$. So our assumption (that $-a^{-1}>0$) must be wrong.

Comment: Thank you! :) I suppose to make it more complete, I should prove that -1<0 as well.

Comment: Yes, that's necessary to the argument; if it's not given (as an assumption, axiom, etc.) then it needs to be shown to finish the argument.

Comment: The fact that -1<0 wouldn't just follow from showing that 1 > 0, and applying trichotomy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28845/discussion-between-user1306-and-jessy-cat).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove it would be by making use of the Density Theorem of rational numbers,
that is, if $a>0\Rightarrow \exists k\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $0<k<a$, then applying arithmetic operations to the inequality we obtain the desired result $0<\frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{k}$.